# Excel4Node: How to download an excel file without saving?

Tags: node.js, excel4node

Using excel4node I am able to write the file to the harddrive. But rather I would like to return it as a download without saving the file on the server. I think the following code is required, but unsure how to use it:

```
wb.writeToBuffer().then(function(buffer) {
  console.log(buffer);
});
```

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: `response.write(buffer)`

Comment: Hi @apfz, Did you get the solution of this issue?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't. As I was unable to get it to work, I left the feature from my project for the moment and focussed on other more important things. I havent tried @Shubh Patels suggestion yet though

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with nodeJS/Express GET Request. Is this what you're looking for ?

```
var xl = require('excel4node');

router.route("/test/").get((req, res) => {
    var wb = new xl.Workbook();
    var ws = wb.addWorksheet('SHEET_NAME');
    ws.cell(1, 1).string('ALL YOUR EXCEL SHEET FILE CONTENT');
    wb.write(`FileName.xlsx`, res);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let binarybuffer = new Buffer(buffer, 'binary');
res.attachment('filename.xlsx'); 
return res.send(binarybuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

//front-end react  --

```
var fileDownload = require('js-file-download');  //npm i js-file-download
    axios({
        url:url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // Important
    }).then((response) => {
        fileDownload(response.data, `FileName.xlsx`);
    });
```